# oracle database 19c - grant [rolename] to [user] error ORA-01917: user or role does not exist

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I use This script to create user and role for oracle database 19c and get error ORA-01917

```
CREATE ROLE C##readonlyrole;

CREATE USER "C##lysjr_ro" IDENTIFIED BY "XXXXXXXPASWORD"  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "XXX_TABLE_SPACE"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "XXX_TABLE_SPACE_TEMP";

GRANT CREATE SESSION to C##readonlyrole;

BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM dba_tables WHERE owner='C##lysjr_ro')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON schema_name.' || x.table_name || 
                                  ' TO C##readonlyrole';
  END LOOP;
END;

GRANT C##readonlyrole TO C##lysjr_ro;
```

But

```
GRANT C##readonlyrole TO C##lysjr_ro;
```

Show error report with result :

```
GRANT C##readonlyrole TO C##lysjr_ro
Error report -
ORA-01917: user or role 'C##lysjr_ro' does not exist
01917. 00000 -  "user or role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    There is not a user or role by that name.
*Action:   Re-specify the name.
```

now what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *not* using quotation marks in your create user command:

```
CREATE USER C##lysjr_ro IDENTIFIED BY XXXXXXXPASWORD  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE XXX_TABLE_SPACE
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE XXX_TABLE_SPACE_TEMP;
```